# as3 flash getChildAt(0).someMethod access

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I can do this
getChildAt(0).alpha = 0;

But this throws an error
getChildAt(0).gotoAndStop(2);

How do I access a movieclip's methods using the display list array?

Answer (score 6):

getChildAt does not return a movieclip, so you need to cast it first, using the `as` keyword:

```
(getChildAt(0) as MovieClip).gotoAndStop(2);
```

Comment: what is the gotoandStop(2) for?